# jPanelMenu add style on menu open

Tags: jquery, addclass, slidingmenu

I need `.jPanelMenu,body{overflow-x:hidden}` only added to these if the menu is open.

I'm using a jquery scroll to scroll back to top. If window is scrolled, and the overflow messes that up. So `.jPanel.open{overflow-x:hidden;}` and `.jPanel.closed{overflow-x:visual}` would work great.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Want to make a fiddle to show the problem? Could definitely help here.

Comment: Yes, and thank you  here: http://jsfiddle.net/ashleigh8/KahqM/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When jPanelMenu is turned on, a data attribute (`data-menu-position`) is added to the `<body>` tag.

You could hook into this attribute for styling:

```
    body[data-menu-position="open"] { }

    body[data-menu-position="closed"] { }
```

Or, you could use the callback functions in the options object to apply a class as you need it. Check out those options here (there are several different callbacks for different timing, so you may have to experiment to find the one you need): http://jpanelmenu.com/#options-before

I haven't added those classes to the plugin, but it's definitely a great suggestion. I'll probably add those to the plugin and push out a new version soon.

Comment: The css fix only half works, because I need the overflow-x:hidden on the html.jPanelMenu also for the mobile. If you remove the overflow-x:hidden from html.jPanelMenu on mobile the slide jumps around and look like it is not working right. So how with the jquery option can I set that. I'm still pretty new to jquery and don't really understand how to accomplish this. Thanks for your help